# How do I uninstall docker-compose?

Tags: macos, docker, docker-compose

I installed docker-compose by following the official documentation: http://docs.docker.com/compose/install/

Now I want to uninstall docker-compose.

```
$ docker-compose -h
```

offers no command for uninstalling, nor does the official documentation offer any instructions.

I deleted my docker-compose.yml file and /usr/local/bin/docker-compose, but I want to make sure that's everything.

I'm using OSX Yosemite 10.10.3 on a MacbookPro.

EDIT: Regarding the installation instructions I followed, I didn't use pip. I used the documented curl command:

```
$ curl -L https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/1.3.1/docker-compose-`uname -s`-`uname -m` > /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
$ chmod +x /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
```

Comment: `sudo find / -name "*docker-compose*" -exec rm -r {} \;` or to test run just add `echo`.. `sudo find / -name "*docker-compose*" -exec echo rm -r {} \;`

Comment: @davidcondrey or just `-delete`...

Comment: Why would you want to do that? It would only delete your local instance of Docker Compose, which comes packaged with a Docker installation.

Comment: @ryanwebjackson In 2015 Docker Desktop didn't exist; docker, docker-compose, and docker-engine were each installed separately. Today I imagine most Mac folks install Docker Desktop. On Linux it's possible to remove the docker compose plugin and keep the rest. See https://docs.docker.com/compose/install/uninstall/

Comment: My point is that you're only affecting one machine by deleting it. What is the purpose of doing so?

Comment: If I recall at the time I wanted a fresh installation of all docker tools on the single Mac I was using. I don't understand what you mean about only affecting one machine. I must be missing something in your question.

Answer (score 95, accepted):

### Documenation

**[Please note that this is now in the docs](https://docs.docker.com/compose/install/#uninstallation)**.

### Coupled Installation and Removal

Note: on Mac [Docker now installs Docker Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/install/).  So the strategy for removal has changed a bit.  If you [uninstall Docker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44346109/how-to-easily-install-and-uninstall-docker-on-macos), and you want to uninstall both, then you also uninstall Docker Compose.

### Individual Removal if Installed Using `curl`

It is commonly installed to `/usr/local/bin/docker-compose` on macs. However, you can run `which docker-compose` to find the exact location.

**Run the following command (*nix systems) to remove:**

```
rm $(which docker-compose)
```

If you get a permission denied error then you will need to prepend `sudo`:

```
sudo rm $(which docker-compose)
```

To verify that it was successful, run the following command which should return nothing:

```
which docker-compose
```

It should say that the command wasn't found.

### Individual Removal if Installed Using PIP

If you've installed Docker Compose using PIP then you can run:

```
pip uninstall docker-compose
```

You may have to use `sudo` if you get a permission denied error:

```
sudo pip uninstall docker-compose
```

Comment: I sent a PR to the Docker Compose documentation to update it with my answer.  It will show up here after a bit: https://docs.docker.com/compose/install/  This was the PR: https://github.com/docker/compose/pull/1619/files

Answer (score 21):

first get docker path by:

> which docker-compose

then it will return path like:`/usr/bin/docker-compose`

then remove it:

> sudo rm -rf /usr/bin/docker-compose

Answer (score 3):

Nowadays docker-compose is part of the docker toolbox.

If you want to **remove everything** that comes with the Docker Toolbox (**including Docker** itself).

You can execute this shell script:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Uninstall Script

if [ "${USER}" != "root" ]; then
    echo "$0 must be run as root!"
    exit 2
fi

while true; do
  read -p "Remove all Docker Machine VMs? (Y/N): " yn
  case $yn in
    [Yy]* ) docker-machine rm -f $(docker-machine ls -q); break;;
    [Nn]* ) break;;
    * ) echo "Please answer yes or no."; exit 1;;
  esac
done

echo "Removing Applications..."
rm -rf /Applications/Docker

echo "Removing docker binaries..."
rm -f /usr/local/bin/docker
rm -f /usr/local/bin/docker-machine
rm -r /usr/local/bin/docker-machine-driver*
rm -f /usr/local/bin/docker-compose

echo "Removing boot2docker.iso"
rm -rf /usr/local/share/boot2docker

echo "All Done!"
```

If you still have the depreciated **Boot2docker** and you want to get rid of it as well.

You can uninstall it by executing the following shell script:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Uninstall Script

if [ "$(which boot2docker)" == "" ]; then
    echo "boot2docker does not exist on your machine!"
    exit 1
fi

if [ "${USER}" != "root" ]; then
    echo "$0 must be run as root!"
    exit 2
fi

echo "Stopping boot2docker processes..."
boot2docker stop && boot2docker delete

echo "Removing boot2docker executable..."
rm -f /usr/local/bin/boot2docker

echo "Removing boot2docker ISO and socket files..."
rm -rf ~/.boot2docker
rm -rf /usr/local/share/boot2docker

echo "Removing boot2docker SSH keys..."
rm -f ~/.ssh/id_boot2docker*

echo "Removing boot2docker OSX files..."
rm -f /private/var/db/receipts/io.boot2docker.*
rm -f /private/var/db/receipts/io.boot2dockeriso.*

echo "Removing Docker executable..."
rm -f /usr/local/bin/docker

echo "All Done!"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also just:

```
 sudo yum remove docker-compose-plugin
```

on RPM-based like Centos

according to: https://docs.docker.com/compose/install/uninstall/

Answer (score -1):

I would use `pip uninstall docker-compose`

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but I didn't use pip to install. Edited my question now.

Comment: I didn't realize that was their installation method.  In that case, then your solution should be complete.

Comment: Can you think of a way to verify whether it was successful? I wouldn't expect any other files to be created during install, but this is precisely what I want to confirm or disprove. :)

Comment: to verify installation run `docker-compose -v`

Answer (score -1):

i saw this mistake when i was run ansible-playbook `FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Unable to load docker-compose. Try pip install docker-compose`
for ubuntu, me help.
Docker-compose not installed because pip3 not upgrade, after i will do

```
pip3 install setuptools-rust
pip3 install --upgrade pip
pip3 install docker-compose
```

its work for me

Comment: `pip3 install docker-compose` won't uninstall anything. Please add some more explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it