# Cannot launch docker desktop for mac

Tags: docker

I installed docker desktop for mac for the first time, but i couldn’t launch it.
I installed it as follows.

・Signed up with this official page(https://www.docker.com/get-started) and clicked download button for Mac intel chip.

・Opened Docker.dmg file and dragged and dropped Docker.app into Applications.

・Did a spotlight search for docker and launched it.

・Clicked on the “open” button on the notification screen that says “Docker.app” is an app downloaded from the Internet. Are you sure you want to open it?

No response from the application after this.

**Current state**

There is a docker app in Applications folder, and Docker in locations(with an eject button).
I cannot launch the app, and use any docker commands.
The other apps work fine and comfortably.

I tried restart my pc, turn off Firewall and FireVault, and installed again,  but the exact same thing happened.

I'm on a MacBook Pro 16 (2019) with the latest version of macOS Big Sur 11.6.

Comment: Did you also allow docker via `Security & Privacy -> General`. You need to unlock first by pressing the lock in the lower left corner to allow apps.

Comment: I cannot find  docker via Security & Privacy -> General. 
I think Security & Privacy -> General only allows you to set a password and whether to allow apps to be downloaded only from the app store or also from an identified developer.

Comment: Try starting the docker-for-mac via spotlight. When the popup `Are you sure you want to open it?` appears don't press ok, but open `Security&Privacy`, then the tab `General`, unlock, and you should see something in the lower half. See also step 4 at [adamtheautomator.com/docker-for-mac](https://adamtheautomator.com/docker-for-mac/)

Comment: Thank you for the very clear web page.
However, I tried following your advice (as stated on the page), I can't find the corresponding entry in security & privacy.

Comment: [this is the solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69552636/cannot-launch-docker-desktop-for-mac#answer-73545528)

Comment: After spending 4 continuous days trying solutions of internet, I upgraded my mac os & it started working straight.

Comment: In my case I just re-installed it. Made sure to replace the currently installed docker desktop app. After installation was done everything started working without problems. Containers, images, and volumes were there nothing was deleted.

Answer (score 462):

I had the same issue on my Mac. It was working well, suddenly, one day it stops working. I was able to run it again by the following method:

1. Go to finder and open `Applications > Utilities > Activity Monitor.app`
2. Find `Docker` or `Docker Desktop` (it was in Not responding mode in my case) and Force Kill the app.
3. Run the following command in Terminal:

   `sudo rm -rf ~/Library/Containers/com.docker.*`
4. Open the setting file in the terminal:

   `sudo nano ~/Library/Group\ Containers/group.com.docker/settings.json`

then find `"filesharingDirectories":`

5. Remove all entries inside this key and leave it as `"filesharingDirectories": [],` save and close the file.
6. Finally go to the Application folder, find `Docker` and run it (wait sometime, it takes a minute or so to run)

**IMPORTANT NOTE: This will delete ALL your containers**

Comment: I did this and purged cache / reset to factory defaults etc using Docker Troubleshoot

Comment: Worked, thank you very much. Note for others: this will delete ALL your containers

Comment: I went to Activity Log, found it, double-clicked on it, and then chose [Quit Process] from the menu that pops up. Then I restarted Docker Desktop and it opened correctly.

Comment: Simply force-quitting docker from the activity monitor works, there's no need to delete anything else. 

Steps: 
1. CMD + Space, 
2. search for the activity monitor
3. while in activity monitor, use the search feature to look for "docker"
4. force-quit all docker activities
5. launch docker

Comment: @EmmanuelNdukwe in my case that was not working, maybe you can see the question, that was the first attempt to start docker desktop, so "filesharingDirectories" was the main reason for that, you can search about that.

Comment: thank you ! I just had to force quit Docker, and I can now access again the docker desktop dashboard

Comment: An additional step that I had to go through to get this working was to delete the "httpProxyOverride" and "httpsProxyOverride" settings from ~/Library/Group\ Containers/group.com.docker/settings.json as this was resulting in connectivity failure whether or not I was logged into the corporate network.

Comment: steos 1-2 worked like a charm for me, so skipped the rest of the steps.

Comment: I had a volume that no longer existed in ~/Library/Group\ Containers/group.com.docker/settings.json

Comment: @EmmanuelNdukwe I had tried force quitting, restarting, everything and it did not work. Removing the lines from the fileSharingDirectories made the difference for us!

Comment: None of this works for me. Would appreciate any other ideas. Not the kind of behavior I expect from a purchased app.

Comment: I uninstalled docker (from Homebrew) and reinstalled using dmg file. Still bad. I cleaned per this answer plus rm -rf $(HOME)/.docker and ~/Library/Group\ Containers/group.com.docker. Finally I have Desktop UI again.

Comment: BE careful. This may remove mounting functionality to files

Comment: This worked! I tried so many things before this, reinstalling docker, purging data, manually removing files from library, none of that worked. Thank you.

Comment: The trick for me was that I had a broken symlink on ~/.docker/config.json. It must just assume it's there and totally hang if it can't open. Not great file handling.. anyways, after `rm ~/.docker/config.json`, it loaded fine.

Comment: Closing docker and step 4. remove filesharingDirectories was enough for me

Comment: Thanks it worked. In my case, I only had to kill docker from "Activity Monitor"

Comment: I followed the steps and made docker desktop run again.  But all the docker images on the local system are gone. How can I get them back? Some of them are not pushed to any image library.

Comment: I only forced it to close and it's back to work again, thanks

Comment: You can also use command + space, which opens up a search prompt, then search "Activity Monitor" to open that instead of using finder

Comment: This worked for me, thanks! I skipped step 3 which left the existing images intact. Not sure but might have been due to removing a directory that was in the list of shared folders.

Comment: Worked on MacOS Ventura 13.2.1 (22D68). Step 4&5 is the crucial part, as it seems.

Comment: Thanks I only had to kill docker from "Activity Monitor" and the charm happen

Comment: Anyone tried everything here and on the other answers only to come up empty handed? I'm stuck. I can use DD without issue on another machine with similar specs and same version OS. Even weirder yet I created a new temporary User on the machine I'm having issues with and it works when logged in to that account, but for w/e reason I cannot get it to start using my main account.

Comment: If this is deleting all the containers then what's the benefit of this solution?
I think a better way is to just follow sepulchre01's answer which solved the issue without deleting anything.

Comment: @pateldhruval Did you run into this problem? Many people like me, after trying everything, when it was not running at all, there was no other way than the above solution. Better let docker tell why this happens, why they are not fixing it. I think everyone should do the same as I sent the request. Please submit a bug request if you have enough time.

Comment: The answer by Emmanuel Ndukwe is much better, and was enough the issue when it happened to me. No need to delete anything and lose all your containers.

Comment: @JohnFantastico, nice that Emmanuel Ndukwe's comments work for you but you can see, that didn't work for others in some comments above.

Answer (score 132):

I just solved this using a similar method to @davidjmcclelland's suggestion:

1. Right click on Docker in Applications folder
2. Select Show Package Contents
3. Click through Contents -> MacOS -> double click on `Docker` exec file

This started up my whale and opened the Docker app for me

[image: macOS-folder-docker]

Comment: Worked, was more simple than the highest voted answer, and didn't require any changes to my settings.

Comment: yep ! work for me too... this method open a terminal starting Docker desktop as expected. But in my case i closed the terminal and then open it again through the mac Dock and all work fine now, thank you !

Comment: This worked for me as well. Once opened, I selected the option to keep it in the dock, and can now start Docker desktop reliably by double-clicking the icon in the Mac dock.

Comment: This is probably out of date, but the docker exec is no longer available in package contents.

Answer (score 51):

What worked for me was opening the activity monitor and searching "docker".

Force quit all activities that are running related to docker.

Retry opening docker.

Comment: yea I just restarted my computer and it worked

Comment: This works without having to delete all your docker instances (like accepted answer suggests)

Answer (score 29):

```
rm -rf Library/Group\ Containers/group.com.docker
rm -rf Library/Containers/com.docker.docker
rm -rf Library/Application\ Support/Docker\ Desktop
```

and restarted Docker Desktop.

Comment: Tried everything else above, this is the only one that actually worked for me. However, it logged me out and then my containers are gone.

Comment: Worked for me. Thankfully I've only started using Docker. Not good that the answer didn't warn about deleting containers!

Comment: [One of] the first two lines helped me

Comment: Only take the deletion approach if the force restart answers don't work.

Answer (score 8):

The issue is most likely "no space left on device" *for docker*.

Previous answers focus on removing all docker data, instead you can allocate more space for docker if you don't want to lose your work:

1. Stop docker(or docker desktop) with Activity Monitor or `kill` command
2. Check how much does docker data currently occupy:

```bash
$ du -sh ~/Library/Containers/com.docker.docker
```

3. Then check how much is allocated for docker:

```bash
$ cat ~/Library/Group\ Containers/group.com.docker/settings.json
{
  ...
  "diskSizeMiB": 51200,
  ...
}
```

In this case it's 50GiB, increase this value with an editor of your choice and save the file.

4. Start docker(or docker desktop)

Answer (score 7):

Docker stopped working for me when I upgraded it. I had a MacOS upgrade pending and I assume the Docker update was for the latest MacOS. I went back to an old Docker download, installed that and Docker is now working again.

Comment: Me too, it was working well then I updated it and then boom, it won't start anymore.

Comment: Me too =( 13.0.1 with version 4.14.+ not work(

Comment: Did my solution fix it for you guys? That is either to upgrade MacOS or to downgrade Docker.
Although I’m more interested if upgrading MacOS fixes it.

Comment: Ran into this. Can confirm that MacOS 13.2.1 (Intel) works with Docker 4.17.0

Answer (score 5):

In my case, the docker desktop icon is lost. After I found this icon through the method by @sepulchre01 [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72998735/3011380), the docker desktop could not be shown up after clicking the docker icon. However, the daemon docker seems running well

```
 0   130     1   0 Fri05PM ??         0:00.13 /Library/PrivilegedHelperTools/com.docker.vmnetd
  501  6892  6891   0 Fri05PM ??         3:35.48 /Applications/Docker.app/Contents/MacOS/com.docker.backend -watchdog -native-api
  501  6893  6892   0 Fri05PM ??         0:07.17 /Applications/Docker.app/Contents/MacOS/com.docker.backend -watchdog -native-api
  501  6899  6892   0 Fri05PM ??         0:39.05 com.docker.vpnkit --ethernet fd:3 --diagnostics fd:4 --pcap fd:5 --vsock-path vms/0/connect --host-names host.docker.internal,docker.for.mac.host.internal,docker.for.mac.localhost --listen-backlog 32 --mtu 1500 --allowed-bind-addresses 0.0.0.0 --http /Users/xxxx/Library/Group Containers/group.com.docker/http_proxy.json --dhcp /Users/xxxx/Library/Group Containers/group.com.docker/dhcp.json --port-max-idle-time 300 --max-connections 2000 --gateway-ip 192.168.65.1 --host-ip 192.168.65.2 --lowest-ip 192.168.65.3 --highest-ip 192.168.65.254 --gc-compact-interval 1800
  501  6901  6892   0 Fri05PM ??         0:10.03 docker serve --address unix:///Users/xxxx/.docker/run/docker-cli-api.sock
  501  6909  6892   0 Fri05PM ??         0:05.09 com.docker.driver.amd64-linux -addr fd:3 -debug -native-api
  501  6910  6892   0 Fri05PM ??         0:06.15 com.docker.extensions -address extension-manager.sock -watchdog
  501  6911  6892   0 Fri05PM ??         0:02.38 com.docker.dev-envs
  501  6920  6909   0 Fri05PM ??         0:02.87 /Applications/Docker.app/Contents/MacOS/com.docker.driver.amd64-linux -addr fd:3 -debug -native-api
  501  6933  6909   0 Fri05PM ??        56:52.24 com.docker.hyperkit -A -u -F vms/0/hyperkit.pid -c 2 -m 5120M -s 0:0,hostbridge -s 31,lpc -s 1:0,virtio-vpnkit,path=vpnkit.eth.sock,uuid=0d513cbc-4d03-4545-b23b-805e5d9d31d8 -U a94747d2-6ca0-4242-9d8b-a2ff5c0a142e -s 2:0,virtio-blk,/Users/xxxx/Library/Containers/com.docker.docker/Data/vms/0/data/Docker.raw -s 3,virtio-sock,guest_cid=3,path=vms/0,guest_forwards=1525 -s 4,virtio-rnd -l com1,null,asl,log=vms/0/console-ring -f kexec,/Applications/Docker.app/Contents/Resources/linuxkit/kernel,/Applications/Docker.app/Contents/Resources/linuxkit/initrd.img,earlyprintk=serial page_poison=1 vsyscall=emulate panic=1 nospec_store_bypass_disable noibrs noibpb no_stf_barrier mitigations=off linuxkit.unified_cgroup_hierarchy=1 console=ttyS0 console=ttyS1 tsc=reliable noapic vpnkit.connect=connect://2/1999 vpnkit.disable=osxfs-data
  501 26403     1   0  9:00PM ??         0:01.31 com.docker.vpnkit --ethernet fd:3 --diagnostics fd:4 --pcap fd:5 --vsock-path vms/0/connect --host-names host.docker.internal,docker.for.mac.host.internal,docker.for.mac.localhost --listen-backlog 32 --mtu 1500 --allowed-bind-addresses 0.0.0.0 --http /Users/xxxx/Library/Group Containers/group.com.docker/http_proxy.json --dhcp /Users/xxxx/Library/Group Containers/group.com.docker/dhcp.json --port-max-idle-time 300 --max-connections 2000 --gateway-ip 192.168.65.1 --host-ip 192.168.65.2 --lowest-ip 192.168.65.3 --highest-ip 192.168.65.254 --gc-compact-interval 1800
  501 26405     1   0  9:00PM ??         0:00.51 docker serve --address unix:///Users/xxxx/.docker/run/docker-cli-api.sock
  501 26412     1   0  9:00PM ??         0:00.26 com.docker.dev-envs
```

Then I try to uninstall the docker and reinstall the latest docker version per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65468254/3011380)

```
sudo rm -Rf /Applications/Docker.app
sudo rm -f /usr/local/bin/docker
sudo rm -f /usr/local/bin/docker-machine
sudo rm -f /usr/local/bin/com.docker.cli
sudo rm -f /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
sudo rm -f /usr/local/bin/docker-compose-v1
sudo rm -f /usr/local/bin/docker-credential-desktop
sudo rm -f /usr/local/bin/docker-credential-ecr-login
sudo rm -f /usr/local/bin/docker-credential-osxkeychain
sudo rm -f /usr/local/bin/hub-tool
sudo rm -f /usr/local/bin/hyperkit
sudo rm -f /usr/local/bin/kubectl.docker
sudo rm -f /usr/local/bin/vpnkit
sudo rm -Rf ~/.docker
sudo rm -Rf ~/Library/Containers/com.docker.docker
sudo rm -Rf ~/Library/Application\ Support/Docker\ Desktop
sudo rm -Rf ~/Library/Group\ Containers/group.com.docker
sudo rm -f ~/Library/HTTPStorages/com.docker.docker.binarycookies
sudo rm -f /Library/PrivilegedHelperTools/com.docker.vmnetd
sudo rm -f /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.docker.vmnetd.plist
sudo rm -Rf ~/Library/Logs/Docker\ Desktop
sudo rm -Rf /usr/local/lib/docker
sudo rm -f ~/Library/Preferences/com.docker.docker.plist
sudo rm -Rf ~/Library/Saved\ Application\ State/com.electron.docker-frontend.savedState
sudo rm -f ~/Library/Preferences/com.electron.docker-frontend.plist
```

The docker works well now.

- Latest Docker version: Docker Desktop 4.11.1
- Mac: 12.1 Monterey Inter Core

Answer (score 5):

The following worked instead

Mac version : 12.5.1

1. Delete Docker form Finder > Applications
2. Restart mac
3. Install docker via command line: https://docs.docker.com/desktop/install/mac-install/#install-from-the-command-line
4. Run the below commands

```
#this gives mac user name
whoami 

sudo chown -R <mac username> /Volumes
sudo chown -R <mac username> /Volumes/Data
```

Now double click on Finder > Applications > Docker ; it opens the window. and also gets into started status

Comment: This answer worked for me in combination with removing these files: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73300670/1059780

Answer (score 3):

I just re-downloaded the dmg and reinstalled the app, selecting "Replace".  Worked fine afterwards.

Answer (score 3):

The top vote answer by Siddiqui Noor worked the first time. But it's not once and for all. Each time I want to open Docker Desktop, I need to perform the same steps, which is unrealistic.

The once-and-for-all answer is:

1. Right click on Docker in Applications folder
2. Select "Show Package Contents"
3. Click through Contents -> MacOS -> right click on Docker Desktop
4. Select "Make Alias".

The Alias is created inside the same directory. Move the alias to the application folder. Now, you can reliably open Docker Desktop in the application folder or find it in the launch pad.

Answer (score 2):

You can run that command:

> softwareupdate --install-rosetta

to use docker desktop for apple silicon.

Answer (score 2):

Use activity monitor and Force quit all running activity related to docker and then start docker from applications again

Answer (score 1):

1. Right-click Docker in Applications folder
2. Select Show Package Contents
3. Double-click Docker Desktop.app
4. Right-click in Dock and select Options -> Keep In Dock

The only thing I use desktop for is to get the image name, so nuking Docker would not work for me.

Answer (score 1):

For me, it did not launch from the desktop. I had to open the application from the launchpad.

Comment: Dont know why but this worked, @docker please fix it up.

Answer (score 1):

Taking inspiration from [the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71861493/5293447), I tried a simpler solution that worked for me.

1. Open Activity Monitor
2. Search for 'Docker'
3. Clicked on the process with the Docker logo
4. Click on the information icon
5. Click Quit
6. After a few seconds of clicking Quit, there were no docker processes in Activity Monitor.
7. Open Docker as usual (I opened Docker from the dock but I imagine any way of opening the docker application should work.)

Comment: This worked OK for me.  If I quit with cmd-q it seems to get in this state, but not if I quit from the docker menu.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried a few of the other solutions here and, while trying them, I ended up discovered what the problem was (in my case):

I have changed the content of the `~/.docker/daemon.json` file to something that was incorrect!

I discovered it by doing @jfunk (redownloaded it and then used "replace".) At that time, when Docker was starting, I got an error saying exactly the problem I was having - pointing me to that file. I fixed it and Docker started smoothly after that (without losing anything I had!)

Answer (score 0):

I found simply doing the following command a few times prompted the GUI to come back. The first sign was I got a popup saying accept licensing or something, the GUI then went back to being hidden, I then force quit all instances of Docker in Activity Monitor and then did the same command again. I think at this point I got a message saying something like docker wasn't running or something, but there is an option to reset Docker to factory settings I did that, same thing no GUI, until I re-run the command a final time and for some reason everything popped up and successfully working again.

`/Applications/Docker.app/Contents/MacOS/Docker --uninstall`

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered this issue today too. My device is MacBook Pro 2021 with M1max chip, installing docker for Apple Silicon 4.27.2. (I use an older version because I failed to run the lastest version and I thought it might work on my machine.)
I tried almost all solutions I can find on stack overflow and github but failed. At the end, when I am about to uninstall docker and install it on another computer, I ran `brew uninstall docker` in my terminal. Suddenly its gui poped out on my screen! (But not having any function because docker is already uninstalled.) After that I downloaded the docker app at its website and install again, everything works.
I have no idea about what have happened. umm hope uninstall it using terminal once would work?

Comment: Please be more specific, you don't need to tell the whole story.

Answer (score -1):

I turned to find logs error.

```bash
cd ~/Library/Group\ Containers/group.com.docker
```

find the DockerAppStderr.txt, 'can't create directory Permission denied'

```bash
sudo chmod 777 ~/Library/Application\ Support
```

after operate, I launch the docker desktop success

Answer (score -1):

Uninstall docker and restart your mac! reinstall it

Answer (score -1):

I tried the steps mentioned in [this comment](https://github.com/docker/for-mac/issues/6867#issuecomment-1580631547) on the GitHub issue tracker for Docker on macOS and it worked.

The steps are as follows:

1. Open a terminal window on your macOS machine.
2. Run the following cmd.

```bash
sudo rm -rf $HOME/.docker/buildx
```

3. Restart the docker app.