# Docker stuck in "Docker Desktop starting..." on Mac

Tags: docker, docker-desktop

I can't get Docker to start on my Mac (Intel). It's just stuck in Docker Desktop starting...
Here are the things I have tried:

- Running with the desktop installer
- Running with the brew installer (brew install --cask docker)
- In the debug menu:

  - Clean /Purge data
  - Reset to factory defaults

Trying to run docker ps in terminal shows:

```
Error response from daemon: dial unix docker.raw.sock: connect: no such file or directory
```

If I quit docker, the `com.docker.vmnetd` process needs to be killed manually.

This problem started around version 4.5.0 Now I am on version 4.12.0., and still the same issue. If I downgrade to a version far back (with the previous UI), it works. But after a while, Docker forces itself to update, which puts me back in this same problem.

Does anyone have any clue what I can try?

Comment: I had the same issue previously, what I did was uninstall docker completely from my mac, and re-installed it via https://docs.docker.com/desktop/install/mac-install/ , restarted my PC after the install, and everything worked fine.

Comment: Unfortunately, I have tried this many times. Without any luck.

Comment: Any update here? Having the same issue. Uninstalled, reinstalled, reinstalled (in just about every combination), upgraded Mac OS version -- nothing works. Not sure why this question was closed.

Comment: Do you have @ in your username and/or home folder? I had that, and after renaming my home folder, it got fixed.

Comment: Same issue on M1 Mac - 4.12.0 failed to start. Had to downgrade to 4.4.2

Comment: I had an `@` in the username and home folder. Creating a new user without the `@` and installing Docker with that user worked for me.

Comment: Might want to try https://stackoverflow.com/a/73017506/1088084