# Why does my docker crash after updating my Mac to Sonoma 14.0?

Tags: docker, macos, electron

After updating my MacOS to Sonoma 14.0, my Docker (desktop) stopped working, and crashed.

Specs:

- System: MacOS Sonoma 14.0
- Hardware: MacBook Pro M1 2020
- Docker: 4.23.0

I have tried to restart the Docker and Mac. I reinstalled the Docker. But none of the attempted solution changed anything.

My full problem report is here:

```
Translated Report (Full Report Below)

Process:               Docker Desktop [3071]
Path:                  /Applications/Docker.app/Contents/MacOS/Docker Desktop.app/Contents/MacOS/Docker Desktop
Identifier:            com.electron.dockerdesktop
Version:               4.24.0 (4.24.0.10)
Code Type:             ARM-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        launchd [1]
User ID:               501

Date/Time:             2023-10-02 09:59:02.1019 +0200
OS Version:            macOS 14.0 (23A344)
Report Version:        12
Anonymous UUID:        4992EFDD-ACD0-DC97-57FF-3B3522CE5D2F

Sleep/Wake UUID:       414F83AA-BFBE-47C4-B0BC-85551AE4BF05

Time Awake Since Boot: 4200 seconds
Time Since Wake:       2777 seconds

System Integrity Protection: enabled

Crashed Thread:        0  CrBrowserMain  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:        EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000

Application Specific Information:
abort() called




Thread 0 Crashed:: CrBrowserMain Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x18af3b11c __pthread_kill + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x18af72cc0 pthread_kill + 288
2   libsystem_c.dylib                      0x18ae82a50 abort + 180
3   Electron Framework                     0x10f825768 node::Buffer::New(v8::Isolate*, char*, unsigned long) + 158392
4   Electron Framework                     0x10f82599c node::OnFatalError(char const*, char const*) + 552
5   Electron Framework                     0x10a3974f4 v8::internal::V8::FatalProcessOutOfMemory(v8::internal::Isolate*, char const*, v8::OOMDetails const&) + 592
6   Electron Framework                     0x10a39747c v8::internal::V8::FatalProcessOutOfMemory(v8::internal::Isolate*, char const*, v8::OOMDetails const&) + 472
7   Electron Framework                     0x10a56bbdc v8::internal::Heap::FinalizeIncrementalMarkingAtomically(v8::internal::GarbageCollectionReason) + 1364
8   Electron Framework                     0x10a56fb7c v8::internal::Heap::EnsureWasmCanonicalRttsSize(int) + 5252
9   Electron Framework                     0x10a56beb8 v8::internal::Heap::stack() + 716
10  Electron Framework                     0x10a56a4c4 v8::internal::Heap::CollectGarbage(v8::internal::AllocationSpace, v8::internal::GarbageCollectionReason, v8::GCCallbackFlags) + 428
11  Electron Framework                     0x10a561e30 v8::internal::HeapAllocator::AllocateRawWithRetryOrFailSlowPath(int, v8::internal::AllocationType, v8::internal::AllocationOrigin, v8::internal::AllocationAlignment) + 492
12  Electron Framework                     0x10a540c78 v8::internal::Factory::AllocateRaw(int, v8::internal::AllocationType, v8::internal::AllocationAlignment) + 604
13  Electron Framework                     0x109487978 v8::internal::FactoryBase<v8::internal::Factory>::NewRawTwoByteString(int, v8::internal::AllocationType) + 84
14  Electron Framework                     0x10a542da4 v8::internal::Factory::NewStringFromUtf8(v8::base::Vector<unsigned char const> const&, unibrow::Utf8Variant, v8::internal::AllocationType) + 256
15  Electron Framework                     0x10a542f80 v8::internal::Factory::NewStringFromUtf8(v8::base::Vector<char const> const&, v8::internal::AllocationType) + 36
16  Electron Framework                     0x10a3b8844 v8::String::NewFromUtf8(v8::Isolate*, char const*, v8::NewStringType, int) + 132
17  Electron Framework                     0x10f9038b0 node::PromiseRejectCallback(v8::PromiseRejectMessage) + 264736
18  Electron Framework                     0x10f803f58 node::Buffer::New(v8::Isolate*, char*, unsigned long) + 21160
19  Electron Framework                     0x10a40460c v8::internal::Accessors::MakeAccessor(v8::internal::Isolate*, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Name>, void (*)(v8::Local<v8::Name>, v8::PropertyCallbackInfo<v8::Value> const&), void (*)(v8::Local<v8::Name>, v8::Local<v8::Value>, v8::PropertyCallbackInfo<v8::Boolean> const&)) + 11236
20  ???                                  0x121e7edd6ac ???
21  ???                                  0x121e0377d30 ???
22  ???                                  0x121e0071df8 ???
23  ???                                  0x121e03764c8 ???
24  ???                                  0x121e03b63d8 ???
25  ???                                  0x121e0008c18 ???
26  ???                                  0x121e01eeb94 ???
27  ???                                  0x121e01f0ac8 ???
28  ???                                  0x121e7e4b08c ???
29  ???                                  0x121e7e4ad28 ???
30  Electron Framework                     0x10a4cbf90 v8::internal::Execution::Call(v8::internal::Isolate*, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Object>, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Object>, int, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Object>*) + 476
31  Electron Framework                     0x10a3b1dd0 v8::Function::Call(v8::Local<v8::Context>, v8::Local<v8::Value>, int, v8::Local<v8::Value>*) + 568
32  Electron Framework                     0x10f776c2c node::CallbackScope::~CallbackScope() + 1744
33  Electron Framework                     0x10f78a0bc node::EmitAsyncDestroy(node::Environment*, node::async_context) + 59168
34  Electron Framework                     0x10f82d604 node::OnFatalError(char const*, char const*) + 32400
35  Electron Framework                     0x10f82e130 node::OnFatalError(char const*, char const*) + 35260
36  Electron Framework                     0x10f82127c node::Buffer::New(v8::Isolate*, char*, unsigned long) + 140748
37  Electron Framework                     0x1094c4bfc uv_random + 1432
38  Electron Framework                     0x1094c8048 uv_async_send + 884
39  Electron Framework                     0x1094d914c uv_free_interface_addresses + 2156
40  Electron Framework                     0x1094c848c uv_run + 380
41  Electron Framework                     0x10964d8b8 node::FreeArrayBufferAllocator(node::ArrayBufferAllocator*) + 18476
42  Electron Framework                     0x10c1cc4ec v8::internal::SetupIsolateDelegate::SetupBuiltins(v8::internal::Isolate*, bool) + 17358556
43  Electron Framework                     0x10c1e6cc4 v8::internal::SetupIsolateDelegate::SetupBuiltins(v8::internal::Isolate*, bool) + 17467060
44  Electron Framework                     0x10c1e72c4 v8::internal::SetupIsolateDelegate::SetupBuiltins(v8::internal::Isolate*, bool) + 17468596
45  Electron Framework                     0x10c234a9c v8::internal::SetupIsolateDelegate::SetupBuiltins(v8::internal::Isolate*, bool) + 17785996
46  Electron Framework                     0x10944c010 0x1092a4000 + 1736720
47  Electron Framework                     0x10c233e1c v8::internal::SetupIsolateDelegate::SetupBuiltins(v8::internal::Isolate*, bool) + 17782796
48  CoreFoundation                         0x18b04fd28 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 28
49  CoreFoundation                         0x18b04fcbc __CFRunLoopDoSource0 + 176
50  CoreFoundation                         0x18b04fa2c __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 244
51  CoreFoundation                         0x18b04e61c __CFRunLoopRun + 828
52  CoreFoundation                         0x18b04dc2c CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 608
53  HIToolbox                              0x1955a6448 RunCurrentEventLoopInMode + 292
54  HIToolbox                              0x1955a6284 ReceiveNextEventCommon + 648
55  HIToolbox                              0x1955a5fdc _BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInModeWithFilter + 76
56  AppKit                                 0x18e828f90 _DPSNextEvent + 660
57  AppKit                                 0x18effcb94 -[NSApplication(NSEventRouting) _nextEventMatchingEventMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 716
58  AppKit                                 0x18e81c43c -[NSApplication run] + 476
59  Electron Framework                     0x10c2357dc v8::internal::SetupIsolateDelegate::SetupBuiltins(v8::internal::Isolate*, bool) + 17789388
60  Electron Framework                     0x10c2339a0 v8::internal::SetupIsolateDelegate::SetupBuiltins(v8::internal::Isolate*, bool) + 17781648
61  Electron Framework                     0x10c1e78e0 v8::internal::SetupIsolateDelegate::SetupBuiltins(v8::internal::Isolate*, bool) + 17470160
62  Electron Framework                     0x10c1b025c v8::internal::SetupIsolateDelegate::SetupBuiltins(v8::internal::Isolate*, bool) + 17243212
63  Electron Framework                     0x10b4aff3c v8::internal::SetupIsolateDelegate::SetupBuiltins(v8::internal::Isolate*, bool) + 3610924
64  Electron Framework                     0x10b4b1850 v8::internal::SetupIsolateDelegate::SetupBuiltins(v8::internal::Isolate*, bool) + 3617344
65  Electron Framework                     0x10b4adbcc v8::internal::SetupIsolateDelegate::SetupBuiltins(v8::internal::Isolate*, bool) + 3601852
66  Electron Framework                     0x1097aaa8c v8::internal::compiler::BasicBlock::set_loop_header(v8::internal::compiler::BasicBlock*) + 13660
67  Electron Framework                     0x1097aba08 v8::internal::compiler::BasicBlock::set_loop_header(v8::internal::compiler::BasicBlock*) + 17624
68  Electron Framework                     0x1097ab838 v8::internal::compiler::BasicBlock::set_loop_header(v8::internal::compiler::BasicBlock*) + 17160
69  Electron Framework                     0x1097aa218 v8::internal::compiler::BasicBlock::set_loop_header(v8::internal::compiler::BasicBlock*) + 11496
70  Electron Framework                     0x1097aa4d8 v8::internal::compiler::BasicBlock::set_loop_header(v8::internal::compiler::BasicBlock*) + 12200
71  Electron Framework                     0x1094d9720 ElectronMain + 128
72  dyld                                   0x18abf9058 start + 2224
....
```

Comment: This will help, but you will lose everything :( 

https://stackoverflow.com/a/71861493

Comment: Just try brew install --cask docker

Answer (score 1):

Suggestions:

1. Confirm that Docker Desktop is compatible with the updated operating system version. If necessary, update to the latest version if available.
2. Try resetting Docker Desktop to its default settings, as well as its configuration and subscriptions.
3. If possible, uninstall Docker Desktop, restart the MacBook Pro, and reinstall Docker Desktop.
4. Check if there are any other conflicting applications that might be causing the crash. Lastly, consider contacting Docker Desktop support for further assistance, providing them with the crash report.