# Why does Colima failed to find Docker daemon

Tags: docker, kubernetes, skaffold, colima

I was using Docker Desktop on my Mac for a long time. Currently Docker desktop causing a huge issues related to starting up. Everytime [it needs some tweak](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69552636/cannot-launch-docker-desktop-for-mac/71861493#71861493) to run or uninstall and install it again, that takes several hours to fix every time I start working.

So I started using other Docker Desktop alternative for mac that is Colima (**Co**ntainer on **Li**nux on **Ma**c) installed with the help of the [Git link.](https://github.com/abiosoft/colima)

And I am using Docker client for Docker runtime by installing it using:
`brew install docker` and I have logged in using `docker login` via terminal.

**The important note here is that** all the above configuration works well with Docker Desktop [but after uninstalling everything related to docker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44346109/how-to-easily-install-and-uninstall-docker-on-macos/65468254#65468254) and start using `Colima`.

While I run `docker info` I got the following message:

```
$ docker info
Client:
 Context:    default
 Debug Mode: false

Server:
ERROR: Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?
errors pretty printing info
```

Here are few other information that might need:

```
$ colima version
colima version 0.4.2
git commit: f112f336d05926d62eb6134ee3d00f206560493b

runtime: docker
arch: x86_64
client: v20.10.17
server: v20.10.11

kubernetes
Client Version: v1.24.1
Kustomize Version: v4.5.4
Server Version: v1.23.6+k3s1
```

Operating System: macOS Monterey
Version: 12.3.1 (21E258)

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 48):

After posting the question on StackOverflow I was non stop searching for a solution. Finally it took a day to fixed it (for me). While searching on google [I have found a solution in this link](https://github.com/nektos/act/issues/1051#issuecomment-1070599087).

Basically `Colima` usage `$HOME/.colima/docker.sock`, so first I checked if there is anything in the `~/.colima` by running `ls -la ~/.colima` and I have found that `docker.sock` is there.

So I set up the DOCKER_HOST by running the following command:

`$ export DOCKER_HOST="unix://$HOME/.colima/docker.sock"`

and then run:

`$ docker info`

Now it shows everything related to Docker Server :)

```
Client:
 Context:    default
 Debug Mode: false

Server:
 Containers: 29
  Running: 19
  Paused: 0
  Stopped: 10
 Images: 19
 Server Version: 20.10.11
 .....
```

Comment: The normal technique (documented in colima docs) is `docker context use colima`, which points your docker context to colima. Or `docker context use default` to go back to docker. You can actually have both running at the same time.

Comment: It was not working for me saying "Current context "colima" is not found on the file system, please check your config file".

Comment: Colima for the last year or so has created a docker context when you `colima start`. You can use `docker context ls` to show the currently available contexts.  I would `docker context rm colima` and then `colima start` to let colima create it again.

Comment: `docker context ls` gives me this result: "Current context "colima" is not found on the file system, please check your config file at /Users/someuser/.docker/config.json"

Comment: Have you tried `docker context use default` first, to switch, or does it give you the same problem? Bottom line is that your .docker/config.json has invalid information in it. You can manually edit it, or even delete it. I'd probably start with `mv .docker/config.json .docker/config.json.bak` and then see how things went.

Answer (score 37):

I have same problem, because i start colima before install docker, i run

```
$ colima delete
$ colima start
```

terminal print:

```
INFO[0000] starting colima                             
INFO[0000] runtime: docker
```

and colima docker worked!

Comment: This worked for me, using MacOS Ventura OCLP'd on a 2012 Macbook pro.

Comment: Or using `$ colima restart`.

Answer (score 5):

Best is to add `docker-host` in `.zshrc` file

```
export DOCKER_HOST="unix://$HOME/.colima/docker.sock"
```

Note that in case you uninstall colima, then again install docker-desktop, then just comment above line of `.zshrc` file

Answer (score 1):

I haved the same issue and the error persisted after `colima delete`, then i use `colima start --edit` and change the runtime to docker

```
# Container runtime to be used (docker, containerd).
# Default: docker
runtime: docker
```

Answer (score 0):

beware, starting with colima 0.4 the socket path is:

```
$HOME/.colima/default/docker.sock
```

(https://github.com/abiosoft/colima/blob/main/docs/FAQ.md#v040-or-newer)

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution would be:

1. Add export `DOCKER_HOST` at end of your `~/.bashrc`:
   `export DOCKER_HOST="unix:///Users/dmitry/.colima/default/docker.sock"`
2. Source your rc file:
   `source ~/.bashrc`
3. Restart colima: `calima stop` and `colima start`

As for me that solution works fine.